# How to resolve javax.microedition.io.connectionnotfoundexception: connectionnotfound error in socket::open : error = 10061

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, java-me

Am having this error with j2me javax.microedition.io.connectionnotfoundexception: connectionnotfound error in socket::open : error = 10061. when am running the j2me mobile emulator it works fine but when i try to input data from the mobile emulator to the database it throws this exception. I even turned of my windows firewall but the problem is still there. Am working with apache tomcat 7, j2me 3.0 SDK and netbeans 7.0 please i need help because I've search the internet trying to resolve this error.